# How to posting message on user wall (offline_access) when user is not logged in

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I got an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating access token: This may be because the user logged out or may be due to a system error. thrown in /var/www/html/kimunita/dev/include/base_facebook.php on line 1106

Answer (score 1):

`offline_access` has been removed by facebook. now you can get the access token with 60 days validity. have a look. https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: Is there any alternative solution to post message on user wall when user is not logged in?

Comment: Yes, and it’s in the document you have just been shown – long-term access tokens.

Comment: while i am generating the extended access token using this link :
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=101769389982769&client_secret=698146eb77c001bdd80cbede103b6c7f&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=AAABcjwhWxDEBAKJJODdFvzR0FquVKMXbLGxa5gwYEmjl4CstPOriP7AF8LgZCFqM8VtzlA2HSWKITOrhTs1Pz6wQM9aS8AGhhlfZBC9a7GftlHdIIZC.

Getting this error: {
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating access token: This may be because the user logged out or may be due to a system error.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190,
      "error_subcode": 467
   }
}